# How to check and implement platform specific code in nativescript app and web app

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

i am developing an angular2seed advanced app. in this i am using localstorage for saving data(its for web app) and the same data stored in nativescript app using appsettings. while running my nativescript app it successfully launch and works perfectly. But while running this in web it shows:

```
(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:5555/node_modules/application-settings.js
```

actually i done platform check in this but its not working in the case of web. What should i do? how can i work both perfectly. am following

```
https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced
```

Comment: Couldn you wrap the import/require in a nativescript platform check using the platform module?

Comment: yes Like this var appSettings = require("application-settings");

Comment: Yea if you're calling that on your web app it will fail obviously. So wrap the import/require inside a platform check so it's only imported for nativescript apps or vice/versa. I don't have much knowledge of the seed but I think it has something to deal with this type of thing. Might try looking in the issues on the repo and see if someone has asked before.